# is it correct to say 'though" in this sentence

Tags: conjunctions

I want to ask my manager something. I tried this

> I  have some questions, though I do know that I have asked you a lot and I am so sorry for losing your time.

Is "though" correct in this context?

Comment: The word _though_ is used acceptably, though I don't think you want to say "losing your time." The idiom is usually "wasting your time" or "taking so much of your time."

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct; you may use it this way. Here it is used to introduce a subordinate clause. Sometimes it may be preceded by even: ‘even though’.

Answer (score -2):

The sentence itself appears incorrect; why not rephrase it to read:

> I have some questions, sir, although I know I have asked you many other questions previously. I am sorry for taking your time.

Comment: Please user proper capitalization. This is a site about English. Also, this answer would be a better answer if you explained **why** the original is not correct, instead of just offering an alternative.

Comment: Yes, reasons are much more helpful for people learning, because then they can apply what they have learned to other situations. If they are just given an answer with no reasons it doesn't help them the next time. [This guide](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for how to give a good answer might help you out :)

Comment: Was the gender of the manager mentioned? Why is it assumed to be a "sir"? Be careful of adding confusing and perhaps incorrect additions to someone who is just learning English.